# Datepicker is sending 0000-00-00 date while i submit empty date input field?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

[here is the code of my date input field, if i submit empty input date field but on view page date is 0000-00-00 instead of empty or nothing ]

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="date_b" placeholder="mm/dd/yy"  class="form-control datepicker" value="<?php
        if (!empty($assessment_goal->date_b)) {
            echo $assessment_goal->date_b;
        }
        ?>" data-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <a href="#"><i class="entypo-calendar"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You sure? Or is that simply the default in your db?

Comment: yes! but actually i don't know how to check default in my db

Comment: check your date field's data type....

Comment: as far as i know, i was not define any default value of any input field

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed   go to db->select table->click structure->check default value->click edit icon of column-> change to null or whatever you want

Comment: In which Format is the Date stored in the Database? Y-m-d?

Comment: i check my data type, data type of date field is Date

Comment: And a Date field has a default ...there is your issue

Comment: Bernhard yes! date save in   Y-m-d formate

Comment: @Alive to Die if i select default as NULL, how is effect on my view?

Comment: @Alive to Die i am select default as NULL for date field but i face same problem

Comment: "Same problem" is likely due to existing values before the change. You know what the problem is now. You need to work out the details yourself or ask another question

Comment: @charlietfl how can i check this default and if i select default as NULL value for date field, how is it effect on my code or view?

Comment: Now you are asking how to do basic debugging

Comment: Use chat room for discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a Function for this the other Day:

```
function ctd($datetime, $format=false, $displayzero=false){
 $timestamp = strtotime($datetime);
 if(!$format){
  $format = 'd.m.Y'; // <---------- your default Date-Format
 }
 if($timestamp > strtotime('0000-00-00 00:00:00')){
  return date($format, $timestamp);
 }else{
  if($displayzero){
   return str_replace(1, 0, date($format, strtotime('0001-01-01 00:00:00')));
  }else{
   return false;
  }
 }
}
```

With this Function it would be enough to write:

```
echo ctd($assessment_goal->date_b);
```

Comment: thank you @Bernhard for this solution

Comment: You are Welcome! Regards from Austria!